# Bash: sed/grep between patterns (including only first pattern)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, grep

I want to extract all substrings starting with "[A-Z]:" and ending with "[A-Z]:" **or the end of the string**

so that if my input is

```
C:\Users\Alex Sim\Libraries\Some Folder D:\Hello world\Something C:\Ran out of names\whatever
```

my output would be

```
C:\Users\Alex Sim\Libraries\Some Folder
D:\Hello world\Something
C:\Ran out of names\whatever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with GNU **sed**:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\([A-Z]:\)/\n\1/g' input.txt
```

The output:

```
C:\Users\Alex Sim\Libraries\Some Folder
D:\Hello world\Something
C:\Ran out of names\whatever
```

Comment: thank you, just informing you you helped me making this script: https://superuser.com/questions/1264874/can-i-drag-and-drop-files-to-an-sh-script-using-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-or-wi